# To what extent the Jewish theatre of the late Antiquity resembled the Greek one?

Tags: ancient-history, jews, classical-antiquity

Sometime ago I had watched the film [Agora by Alejandro Amenábar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agora_%28film%29) Although the film's idea is impressing, it stroke me with some suspicious historical details. For example, the Christian monks are wearing dress with short sleeves and marching in rows as some fascist paramilitary group.

Similarly, the supposed Jewish theatre resembled a performance from 19th century Eastern Europe.

Before I thought that Jewish theatre at the time in most details resembled and imitated the Greek theatre. The performers should not wear any specific Jewish dress and hairstyle and the performance should be a play rather than just music and dance.

So how much the Jewish theatre of the time resembled the Greek one?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I don't think there was any Jewish theatre at all at the time. I don't have an academic source at hand but [this webpage](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/culture/2/Theatre_and_Dance/Theatre/Premodern.shtml) seems to sum up things pretty well. Look especially in the section "Changing Attitudes under Hellenism".

Comment: So what a performance was in the theater when the incident described in the film happened (such incident in fact took place)?

Comment: @Anixx: I don't know about such an incident (haven't seen the movie too). Can you provide details?

Comment: [Sepphoris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepphoris) had a Roman theatre.